# Assign value to id in html link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following link that passes an id to my controller to render a report.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetReport", new { type = "PDF", id = 12345})" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Print Report</a>
```

I would like to assign this value id in the link above to the result I have returned from the database in the call below....

```
// Global variable
var DocumentID = null;

$('#Save').click(function(e) {

     if (document.forms[0].checkValidity()) {

         e.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({
             url: "/Home/SaveDetails",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
             contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
             success: function(result) {
             if (result > 0) {
                 //Assign return value to DocumentID
                 DocumentID = result;
                 alert("This work request has been successfully saved in database. The Document ID is: " + result);
              } else {
                alert("The Work Request was not saved, there was an issue.");
              }
          },
          complete: function() {
              // Hide loading image.
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // Handle error.
              alert(errorThrown);
          }
      });
    } else {
        alert("Form is not valid");
    }
});
```

The call above works and returns a DocumentID and displays this in an alert with success.  The link above works if the id has a hard-coded value; I would just like to make this value dynamic.

Comment: Can you rephrase to explain which ID you mean? the ID of the link? <a>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above suggestions will generate an error for an unsupported pseudo, in this case 'contain' which is not available or known to the anchor tag.  There is also an error with the syntax of putting the DocumentID in the Url.Action.  I was not able to get this to work, instead I found another error: Too many characters in literal.

Instead give your anchor an **id** and find that **id** using jQuery and replace it's href attribute, this is done in the second line of code under **Javascript**.

**html**:

```
<a href="#" **id="Report"**>Print Report</a>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var DocumentID = result; var href = '@Url.Action("GetReport")?type="PDF"&id=' + DocumentID + ''; 
$("#Report").attr('href', href);
```

Take note of two things. The URL is formed and the anchor tag is found differently versus previous suggestions.

This has been tested and works for parameters of type string and int, respectively in your callback function to handle getting the report.  If you want two strings then add an additional double-quote around the DocumentID like this: id=" ' + DocumentID + ' "';

Answer (score 2):

```
if (result > 0) {
   //Assign return value to DocumentID
   var DocumentID = result;
   var href = '@Url.Action("GetReport", new { type = "PDF", id =' + DocumentID +'})';  
   $("a:contain('Print Report')").attr('href', href);               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your ajax-success handler just set the href of the anchor to whatever you want

```
var newHref = '@Url.Action("GetReport", new { type = "PDF", id = '+DocumentID +'})';

$('a').attr('href',newHref);
```

Comment: Wont work, Hint: 1. `newHref` should use `'`. 2. `$('a')` can select any other anchor tag

Comment: Updated the code.  As Karna suggested you will need to add a better selector than just $('a') .

Comment: @BrianEvans: href should be `'@Url.Action("GetReport", new { type = "PDF", id =' + DocumentID +'})';`